# What is the relationship between class and data types in class diagram?

Tags: struct, uml, relationship, enumeration, class-diagram

I'm working on a class diagram and I'm using the Enterprise Architect.

Suppose that we have a class.
I should use a struct data type that is a global data type and all classes use it.
Also I should define another struct data type that it is supposed to be used inside the class.
I have this scenario for an enumeration.

The question that I have is that what kind of relationship(composition, aggregation, dependency, etc.) should I use in the class diagram for private/public struct and enumeration data types?

Comment: The type of relation is dependency, but we usually don't model these explicitly since they are already used as the type in attributes or parameters, unless you wanted to highlight this fact.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The term "struct" is C-specific. A more general term is "record". A record type is called a "structured data type" in UML. As a UML classifier, it is modeled like a class in a UML class diagram, but with the keyword ("stereotype") `dataType`.  When you say "all classes use it", do you mean that all classes have an attribute the range of which is this structured data type? Maybe this article answers your question: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/data-type.html

Comment: My question is about the relationships between classes and struct data types. suppose that we have a class which it has an attribute that its data type is a struct. as you said, struct is C_specific. In EA you can add a class to your class diagram and change its stereotype to struct to generate a code like: `typedef struct sampleName {int attr1; char atrr2;};`. So my question was only about relationships that @GeertBellekens answered it. thank you both for commenting.